# NCover wait command for report generation

Tags: synchronization, ncover

Hi I am trying to collect unit test coverage from nCover. I am using below commands.

But the Ncover report command is executed immediately after ncover run. This is causing sync issue because code central is taking little extra time, about 30 seconds for generate the reports.

Hence receiving error. Want to know how can i make sure the Ncover report command is executed only after code central gas captured the data.

**Commands:**

NCover run --project="UnitTestCoverage" -- "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe" /testcontainer:UnitTest.dll"

NCover report --project="UnitTestCoverage" --file:"D:\CalviAM_UnitTests.html" Error:

======= ERROR: 2015-09-04T15:14:37 Error in server request: /executions/report.json The remote server returned an error: (422) Error+creating+report. ERROR: 2015-09-04T15:14:37 No file created.